# Order By in nhibernate column mapping

Tags: nhibernate

I have a parent - child node pattern the parent node has a collection of children nodes. The nodes have a property of position for ordering. I use this position property in my mapping file to order by. This works ok until I come to eager load the children which creates an left outer join and the position column is then ambigous. I have tried just adding Children.Position to the order by statement and this creates an error of unknown bound column. If there any way to specify this column?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have better luck by using an indexed collection (`<list/>`).

Comment: That's fine. how do i specify the order of the list in the database and collection?

Comment: a list has a <list-index/> element, which maps the element's index in the list to a db column.